# CSS - content not be reduced as i thought

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make responsive content box

[image]

the problem is that when I reduce the size of browser a lot,
the content(yellow) does not shrink at the end and just shows overflow-x.

I want it to be shrink properly until min-width..

```css
.content_wrapper{
    max-width: 1330px;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.content_box{
    width: calc(18%);
    height: 300px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 166);
    margin:  1%;
    
}
 @media all and (max-width: 600px){
    .content_box{
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    } 
    .content_wrapper{
        padding:0 15px;
        margin: 0;
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="content_wrapper">
        <div class="content_box"></div>
        <div class="content_box"></div>
        <div class="content_box"></div>
        <div class="content_box"></div>
      ~~~~

    </div>
```

here's codepen

https://codepen.io/qwfwqf/pen/eYdqNZQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your code on codepen.io. You simply need to remove or your adjust your `min-width` attribute in for your `html` tag in your CSS.

For example, if you write:

```
html {
    min-width: 300px:
}
```

... your boxes will resize correctly with the screen size.